# How to print the contents of array from an COUNT(*) ORDER BY Statement in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

How would I print the contents of the following array :

```
$sql=
"
SELECT shop_order_location, COUNT(*) FROM shop_orders
LEFT JOIN product
ON shop_orders.shop_order_product_id=product.product_id
WHERE 
DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
BETWEEN '2014-04-01' and '2014-05-01' AND brand = '226' AND shop_order_action = 'Sale'
GROUP BY shop_order_location";

$total = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));
```

...

This query generates the following table

```
Bawtry      36
Chain       10
Grantham    10
Internet    14
```

I want to pass each integer result into a separate PHP variable, i.e. $Bawtry = 36, $Chain=10 etc. and then print each value separately.

Thanks

*** UPDATE ***

```
<?
$sql=
"
SELECT shop_order_location, COUNT(*) FROM shop_orders
LEFT JOIN product
ON shop_orders.shop_order_product_id=product.product_id
WHERE 
DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
BETWEEN '2014-04-01' and '2014-05-01' AND brand = '226' AND shop_order_action = 'Sale'
GROUP BY shop_order_location";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   ${$row['shop_order_location']} = $row['COUNT'];


}
?>
```

This code in it's current state isn't appearing to do anything - when I run the php script, it returns a black page.

I'm trying to pass the contents of the array to separate variables, i.e.

$Bawtry = 36
$Chain = 10

So how would I separate out the results of the array and pass them into separate variables?

***UPDATE 2***

```
/*
*   Overall array by shop location counting total pairs
*/

$sql = "SELECT shop_order_location
             , COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
        FROM shop_orders
        LEFT JOIN product ON shop_orders.shop_order_product_id = product.product_id
        WHERE
    DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
        BETWEEN '".$start."' and '".$end."' AND brand = '".$bid."'
        AND shop_order_action = 'Sale'

    GROUP BY shop_order_location";

    $result1 = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($overall = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    ${$overall['shop_order_location']} = $overall['TOTAL'];
    } 
/*
*   Mens array - counting pairs of brand 
*/

$sql2 = " SELECT shop_order_location
             , COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
        FROM shop_orders
        LEFT JOIN product ON shop_orders.shop_order_product_id = product.product_id
        WHERE   
    DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
        BETWEEN '".$start."' and '".$end."' AND brand = '".$bid."'
        AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' AND category = 'Mens'

    GROUP BY shop_order_location";

    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
    while ($mens = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
    ${$mens['shop_order_location']} = $mens['TOTAL'];
    }
/*
*   Ladies array - counting pairs of brand
*/  

$sql3 = " SELECT shop_order_location
             , COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
        FROM shop_orders
        LEFT JOIN product ON shop_orders.shop_order_product_id = product.product_id
        WHERE  
    DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
        BETWEEN '".$start."' and '".$end."' AND brand = '".$bid."'
        AND shop_order_action = 'Sale' AND category = 'Ladies'

    GROUP BY shop_order_location";

    $result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
    while ($ladies = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
    ${$ladies['shop_order_location']} = $ladies['TOTAL'];
    }
/*
*   SUM query - sales total cost
*/

$sql4 = "SELECT SUM(shop_order_price)
        FROM shop_orders
        LEFT JOIN product ON shop_orders.shop_order_product_id = product.product_id
        WHERE  
    DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
        BETWEEN '".$start."' and '".$end."' AND brand = '".$bid."' AND shop_order_action = 'Sale'";

$result4 = mysql_query($sql4) or die(mysql_error());
```

So could the array results be passed like so :

```
while($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($result4)){
        ?>

        <?
        $showtotal = $row4['SUM(shop_order_price)'] ;
        $showaverage = $row4['SUM(shop_order_price)'] / $total ;
        ?>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"><strong><?=$brand['name'];?></strong></td>
                    <!-- Bawtry Mens figure -->
                    <td align="center"><?=$mens['Bawtry'];?></td>
                    <!-- Bawtry Ladies figure -->
                    <td align="center"><?=$ladies['Bawtry'];?></td>
                    <!-- Overall Bawtry Figure -->
                    <td align="center"><?=$overall['Bawtry'];?></td>
```

Comment: You want to dynamically create the variables with the names provided from the DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT shop_order_location
             , COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
        FROM shop_orders
        LEFT JOIN product ON shop_orders.shop_order_product_id = product.product_id
        WHERE DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
              BETWEEN '2014-04-01' and '2014-05-01' AND brand = '226' 
              AND shop_order_action = 'Sale'
        GROUP BY shop_order_location";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   ${$row['shop_order_location']} = $row['TOTAL']; 
}
echo $Bawtry; //Check assignment
echo ${'Bawtry'}; //It is better to access your variables this way in case there are strings with spaces in the 'shop_order_location' column
```

Comment: Sorry, That was by mistake.

Comment: OP is using `mysql_` btw.

Comment: Not about OP's sample data but, I just want to know, what happens if `shop_order_location` has a space between characters? like, `New York`. I guess then it won't create a variable like `$New York` because its invalid.

Comment: $sql=
"
SELECT shop_order_location, COUNT(*) FROM shop_orders
LEFT JOIN product
ON shop_orders.shop_order_product_id=product.product_id
WHERE 
DATE(CONCAT(shop_order_year,'-',shop_order_month,'-',shop_order_day))
BETWEEN '2014-04-01' and '2014-05-01' AND brand = '226' AND shop_order_action = 'Sale'
GROUP BY shop_order_location";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   ${$row['shop_order_location']} = $row['COUNT']; 
}
- This returns a blank page?

Comment: Would I need to print seperately $row['Bawtry'] ?

Comment: @Log1c : Thank you for a tip.I know, it is not a good solution,bit it can be accessed like `${'New York'}`.

Comment: @Aphex22 : What is the point?There is now field `Bawtry` in your table.

Comment: @Aphex22 A possible reason you are getting a blank page is the `COUNT` in `$row['COUNT']` if that column doesn't exist in your table, you may  need to do `COUNT(*) as COUNT` but that's not a good idea to use that word, since it's an SQL function.

Comment: @Notulysses - Sorry one more question, could I declare this further down the script as <?=$row['Bawtry'] ? I've created 3 other similar SELECT statements where Bawtry would be the same. Therefore I need to differentiate so, could they be declared as $total['Bawtry'], $mens['Bawtry'] and $ladies['Bawtry'] ? I've tried this and it returns a blank result... (see my new edit above)

Comment: @Aphex22 : For the first query you can do `${$row['shop_order_location'] == 'Bawtry' ? 'totalBawtry' : $row['shop_order_location']}` . And so on for every other query.

Comment: @Notulysses - that's great. One last question, how would I get the total of the count in each particular query. So to retrieve the total of all the locations. example `totalBawtry + totalChain + totalGrantham .. etc`

Comment: @Aphex22 : Just use `COUNT` without a `GROUP BY` clause to apply it to the whole set.